# Dealing with an opencv image (bytes, encoded as jpg) on a Flask API

Tags: python, opencv, flask, python-imaging-library, microsoft-custom-vision

### My Challenge

I need to send and receive images using Flask, for doing realtime object detection over 1000's of camera streams.

#### Part 1: Sending my video frames to the API

**I don't want to save the image frames on my disk, nowadays I don't have .png/.jpg files for sending to the Flask API.** I already have image data in memory as a `numpy.array` (I'm using `cv2.VideoCapture()` to extract the frames from the video streams).

**How can I send these bytes of the `numpy.array` to the Flask API?**

Nowadays I'm trying to encode an image with `cv2.imencode()`, convert it to bytes and then encode it using base64.

```py
### frame is a numpy.array with an image
img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1]
img_bytes = img_encoded.tobytes()
```

So `img_bytes` is something like that:

```py
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x04\x03\x02\x02\x02\x02\x05\x04\x04\x03'
```

I'm trying to send `img_bytes` on my `requests.post()`:

```py
files = {'imageData': img_bytes}
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/image', files=files)
```

I'm receiving `<Response [200]>`, but the API is not working as expected. I believe my Flask server is not dealing well with this encoded bytes... So my problem is probably on Part 2.

#### Part 2: Receiving image bytes on my Flask server and converting it to a PIL.Image

I've defined a function `predict_image()` that receives the output of `PIL.Image.open()` and perform all the object detection tasks.

**My problem is that my variable `imageData` apparently can't be opened correctly by `PIL.Image.open()`. The `type()` of `imageData` is `<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>`.**

In this snippet below my webservice is retrieving the image received on the request and it's executing `predict_image()` object detection over it:

```py
def predict_image_handler(project=None, publishedName=None):
    try:
        imageData = None
        if ('imageData' in request.files):
            imageData = request.files['imageData']
        elif ('imageData' in request.form):
            imageData = request.form['imageData']
        else:
            imageData = io.BytesIO(request.get_data())

        img = Image.open(imageData)
        results = predict_image(img)
        return jsonify(results)

    except Exception as e:
        print('EXCEPTION:', str(e))
        return 'Error processing image', 500
```

I'm not receiving an error while sending images to the API, but the API is not working as expected. I believe it's not converting the bytes back to an image on the right way.

**What am I missing in this code? What do I need to do with the object `imageData` before opening it with `PIL.Image.open()`?**

Comment: Some other details.. I have a set of Virtual Machines on Azure that are connected to several camera streams (more than 1000 surveillance cameras).
I have the objective of performing object detection efficiently (costing less than 12 USD/camera/month) executing @ 2 FPS (so I need to process 2000 on my object detection API).
I'm building a Docker container for running on a Kubernetes cluster.
I don't want to save the frames on the disk due to cost restrictions, I would have a processing time overhead if I saved the images on the disk before processing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a little mistake in my code, I was trying to send `img_encoded` on the post instead of `img_bytes`. Now it's all working.

#### Part 1: making the request

```py
### frame is a numpy.array with an image
img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1]
img_bytes = img_encoded.tobytes()

files = {'imageData': img_bytes}
response = requests.post(url,
files=files)
```

#### Part 2: processing the received bytes

```py
def predict_image_handler(project=None, publishedName=None):
    try:
        imageData = None
        if ('imageData' in request.files):
            imageData = request.files['imageData']
        elif ('imageData' in request.form):
            imageData = request.form['imageData']
        else:
            imageData = io.BytesIO(request.get_data())

        img = Image.open(imageData)
        results = predict_image(img)
        return jsonify(results)

    except Exception as e:
        print('EXCEPTION:', str(e))
        return 'Error processing image', 500
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sending img_encoded or img_bytes to 'imageData'? I do think that sending img_bytes as base64 could cause a behavior like that. The werkzeug.datastructures.
FileStorage should proxy the stream methods, but have you tried using imageData.stream?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to open imageData.stream on the Image.open() method. The error persisted.

Comment: I'm trying to send img_bytes to 'imageData'. Thanks for highlighting this, I've corrected the code snippet on my question above.

Comment: I agree that base64 can fix that, but I've tried to use base64 with the werkzeug.datastructures and I didn't manage to make it work right.